# Automatic protection of columns based on dates in header row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to automatically protect columns where a header row contains a date based on whether the date in the google sheet app script

Here is a screenshot of the sheet:[image: sheet image].

I have tried and created a script that can work but it showing an error in getting last column please suggest if any edit needs to be done I am also attaching the screen shot of the error please check it out also

Script -

```js
function Lock_Cells() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); 
  var lastcolum = sheet.getLastColumn();
for (var i = 3; i <= lastcolum; i++){
 var today = sheet.getRange(0,3).getValue();
  var Check_date = sheet.getRange(5,i).getValue();
  if (Check_date < today){
     var Lock_Range = sheet.getRange(5,i,50);
     var protection = sheet.getRange(Lock_Range).protect();
     var description = "colum " + i;                 
     protection.setDescription(description);
     var eds = protection.getEditors();
     protection.removeEditors(eds);
  }}}
```

Screenshot of error - [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4CYa.png]

Thanks to you that problem is solved and now the sheet is showing the last column but now when I run the function it is showing an error and is not completing the script I have attached the screenshot of the error and the error showing is  -

> Error Exception: The starting row of the range is too small. Lock_Cells   @ Code.gs:11

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDK9g.png

Comment: Did you code something so far?

Comment: You can compare dates numerically by using the methods `valueOf()` or `getTime()`.

Comment: I searched about it till now I found this relevant enough function Lock_Cells() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (var i = 3; i <= 20; i++){var Check_Cell = "E" + i;
var Temp = sheet.getRange(Check_Cell).getValue();
if (Temp == "Locked"){
var Lock_Range = "C" + (i + 2) + ":D" + "i";
var protection = sheet.getRange(Lock_Range).protect();
var description = "Row " + i;                 
protection.setDescription(description);
var eds = protection.getEditors();
protection.removeEditors(eds);}}}'

Comment: but need some help. 1st want to define the parameter in IF/ELSE statement that if today date less than the date in the column header the column should be protected automatically it should deploy else not.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details. Comments are intended for giving feedback.

Comment: Error messages should be add as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error showed in the screenshot (Cannot read property 'getLastColumn' from null) occurs because the spreadsheet hasn't a sheet named `Sheet 1` (`var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');`). To fix this error replace `'Sheet 1'` by the correct sheet name.

The code has other errors too:

```
var today = sheet.getRange(0,3).getValue();
```

`getRange` requires values equal or greater than 1

```
var Lock_Range = sheet.getRange(5,i,50);
var protection = sheet.getRange(Lock_Range).protect();
```

`getRange` can't use a Class Range object as argument. Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet for the valid arguments for `getRange`.

Comment: Thanks to you that problem is solved and now the sheet is showing the last column but now when I run the function it is showing an error and is not completing the script I have attached the screenshot of the error and the error showing is - Error Exception: The starting row of the range is too small. Lock_Cells @ Code.gs:11

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDK9g.png

Comment: @akshat Errors as well code should be added as text, not as image.

Comment: I am really sorry for that and it won't be repeated again                                                         error showing is - Error Exception: The starting row of the range is too small. Lock_Cells @ Code.gs:11                                                                                                      please suggest how I can resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for your help the script is working fine but I need a little help with how to use dates in the script as I have assigned date to every column and assigned today's date to a particular cell when I am getting the value from them and comparing them in if statement that is not matching as the phrase is different between them can you tell how I can solve that issue                                        Date format coming in today() formula in cell - Wed May 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021
Date format coming in today() formula in cell  -Sun May 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: I suggest you to spend some time learning the JavaScript basics, more specifically about data types and objects. In the particular case of date values in Google Sheets they are passed as JavaScript Date objects. In JavaScript the way to compare to Date objects is by using the valueOf or getTime. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/1595451

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Ruben i completed the script yesterday and all your help was amazing thanks.